# Bash Split strings on pattern match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have data such as

```
ID | Name | Grade
1|Robin Hood so hood | A
2|Gwen Stack DO Rick Stacy |C
3|Bling s/o Peter| A
```

where so is son of, DO is daughter of, S/O is son of.

I am gazed How I can arrive to

```
     ID | Name | Grade
    1|Robin Hood| A
    2|Gwen Stack  |C
    3|Bling| A
```

As at end I will be mailing these guys there grades where I am not willing to feed full string just Name

I was trying to use while loop, with awk which gives 2nd field into array then for loop to array which was uncessfull

Any SED or AWK method ??

Comment: If you just want ot remove `so, DO, s/o` you can do `sed -r 's/ (so|DO|s\/o) / /'`. If that's not what you want, please clarify your question

Comment: updated the question, I want string before `so|DO|s\o`

Comment: In the case where ID = 3, you have "Bling  Peter", which are strings both before and after `s/o`. Do you really just want to have "Bling" there?

Comment: yes Only Bling as that what is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak 's~ [sSdD]/*[oO] [^|]*~~' file
ID | Name | Grade
1|Robin Hood|A
2|Gwen Stack|C
3|Bling|A
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -F ' [sSdD]/?[oO] [^|]*' '{print $1 $2}' file
ID | Name | Grade
1|Robin Hood|A
2|Gwen Stack|C
3|Bling|A
```

Comment: I haven't understood `[^|]*~~'` this part of sed

Comment: `[^|]*` matches 0 or more characters before a pipe

Comment: I never used `~~` in regex expression [used only as condition but not expression. what is `~~`

Comment: `~` is just an alternate sed delimiter. We could also use: `'s# [sSdD]/*[oO] [^|]*##'`

Comment: Oh Just skipped out of mind, as i have habit of using `s///g`

Comment: +1 Upvote: I just realized few days ago if we accept answer in just few minutes others may not get time to comeup with there solution. So I am waiting for other potential ways of solving it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95614/discussion-between-ashish-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

sed

```
sed -r 's/(so|DO|S[/]O)[^|]+([|])/\2/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/s\/o Peter/,"")}{sub(/d \| A/,"\ |A")}NR>1{print $1,$2, $NF}NR==1' file
ID | Name | Grade
1|Robin Hood |A
2|Gwen Stack |C
3|Bling | A
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer should feel straightforward as it is using *|* as the field separator, and the **sub** is only working on the second field.  It is also making sure that *so*, *DO*, and *s/o* are separate from names by making the regex in the **sub** take into account spaces on either side of the three:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} sub(/ (s\/?o|DO) .*/, "", $2) + 1' file
ID | Name | Grade
1|Robin Hood| A
2|Gwen Stack|C
3|Bling| A
```

One other thing -- it looks like from the middle part of your question you may be wanting case insensitivity.  If you have **gawk**, you can use *IGNORECASE*.  Otherwise, here is the edited regex.

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} sub(/ ([Ss]\/?|[Dd])[Oo] .*/, "", $2) + 1' file
```

Here is the one if you want to accept case insensitive *D/O* as well.

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} sub(/ [SsDd]\/?[Oo] .*/, "", $2) + 1' file
```